# arshaw Jquery full calender not working in force.com enterprise edition

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, jquery, css

I have used this http://www.codebycody.com/2013/06/create-calendar-view-in-salesforcecom.html to integrate jquery calendar..
It's working fine with developer edition but same code if i copy in force.com enterprise edition m not getting information in the calendar.

Comment: Two things come to my mind,
1. ~Did you move the static resources to production?
2. Can you post code/ Javascript console log for review?

Comment: Yeah I have moved from sandbox to production ..but it's neither working in sandbox nor in production but it's working in developer edition

Comment: Code is there in that link

Comment: Same steps i have followed

Comment: Console log: Deprecation warning: moment construction falls back to js Date. This is discouraged and will be removed in upcoming major release. Please refer to https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1407 for more info.
Momentmin:6 Deprecation warning: moment().zone is deprecated, use moment().utcOffset instead. https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/1779
https://login.salesforce.com/17181/logo180.png Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)